# How do connect facebook page likes with webpage likes?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, seo, facebook-like

I have a webpage where I have placed a like button. Now I have also created a facebook page for this site but the problem is that the likes is separate? How do I connect them.

This is the website : http://www.biss.se/
And this is the facebook site : http://www.facebook.com/www.biss.se?skip_nax_wizard=true

Comment: Your 'like' on the website needs to point to the facebook page url for the likes to be 'synced' between website and fb page.

Comment: But this means that I will lose the likes I already got on my webpage?

Comment: yes. no way to join them up im afraid.